# Post cvs data with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to post data with ajax but in console i recive something like.. Uncaught ReferenceError: file is not defined

This is my input with my button to upload data:

```
<div id='file_browse_wrapper'>
  <input class="iconos" type="file" name="File Upload" id='file_browse' accept=".csv" />
</div>
  <label id="url-archivo"><b>Selecciona tu archivo...</b></label>
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="carga-archivo">Subir</button>
```

This is my jquery/ajax:

```
$("#carga-archivo").click(function () {
                    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("file_browse");
                    if (fileUpload .value != null) {
                        var uploadFile = new FormData();
                        var files = $("#file_browse").get(0).files;
                        // Add the uploaded file content to the form data collection
                        if (files.length > 0) {
                            uploadFile.append('file-'+i, file);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/2/delivery/client/massive",
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                data: uploadFile,
                                type: 'POST',
                                success: function () {
                                   alert("file upload successfuly");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

But the data is not POST i think is something missing

Comment: Exactly what it says. Where did you set/define `file`?

Comment: i catch the file from my input

Comment: You don't. The variable `file` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a variable called `files`, but are using a variable called `file`.  Try changing this portion of your code:

```
var file = $("#file_browse").get(0).files;
// Add the uploaded file content to the form data collection
if (file.length > 0) {
    uploadFile.append('file-'+i, file);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/2/delivery/client/massive",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: uploadFile,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function () {
           alert("file upload successfuly");
        }
    });
}
```

This just renames the `files` variable to `file` and changes the one other place that used `files`.